# Java library for Date scanning (like Scanner for number)?

Tags: java, regex

*Scanner.class* give many useful tools to analyse numbers, like *.hasNext*_() and *.next*_() methods which can be triggered to specific traitments.

Is somewhere something like this, for Date : in a first time it would be to detect dates in a *String*, and adapts response to the format (*mm/dd/yy|dd/mm/yy|yyyymmdd*, are seconds inside, are letters inside, is four digits year, is negative ...) .

*Edit for responses*

- Scanner give more than `SimpleDateFormat` it is able to return `MatchResult` and all is already done (and tested), Is such work is already done, or have I to developp it (re-invent wheel?)
- Negative date for before JC periods
- mm/dd/yy are from English, dd/mm/yy from other European, yyyymmdd from OS, so finding those differences gives different responses to apply.

*Edit2*

Calendar is a pretty tool, just know if somebody have already add on it the method above.

Comment: Try using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the input String.

Comment: How would you tell mm/dd/yy and dd/mm/yy appart?

Comment: There are always input that doesn't give any clue for you to detect the format. Usually, you should know the format before interpret the string as date.

Comment: @nhahtdh certainly, but Scanner detect it for me!

Comment: @cl-r: I don't see any method in Scanner that parse Date. SimpleDateFormat uses heuristics to guess the input, but it is not totally reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/) library. It's pretty cool. It can parse different kinds of dates including "today" "tommorow" "next Friday". Drawbacks is that you cannot really customize it. It has predefined rules for parsing dates and if you want to add/modify them you have to get source code and then compile your own version of natty.

Comment: It is exactly what I need. Thanks! I found also https://github.com/joestelmach/natty/blob/master/src/main/java/com/joestelmach/natty/WalkerState.java